# ExtJs extend component issue

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a extend FormPanel:

```
Ext.ns('myapp');

myapp.StandartForm = Ext.extend(Ext.FormPanel, {
id: 'myForm'
,xtype: 'test'
,frame:true    

,initComponent: function(){
    var self = this;

        this.editWindow = new Ext.Window({
            id: 'editWSWin', 
            layout: 'fit',
            title:this.editPanelTitle,
            autoScroll:false,
            width:300,
            html:'hi'
        });


     var config = {                 
        items: [{
            layout:'column',
            items:[this.grid],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Edit',
                id: "editBtn",                    
                handler: this.editFormCreate,
                scope: this,
                hidden: this.editbuttonHidden,
                disabled:true
            }] 
        }]};

        // apply config
        Ext.apply(this, config);
        Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config);

        myapp.StandartForm.superclass.initComponent.call(this);      

}

, editFormCreate : function (){
    this.editWindow.show();
}
});
Ext.reg(myapp.StandartForm.prototype.xtype, myapp.StandartForm);
```

In this panel i press button `Edit` and window showing. After i close window and press `Edit` button again but get error:

```
TypeError: b.dom is undefined
```

I think it's mean that my window undifined.
How can i extend FormPanel to be able use window correctly?

**UPDATE**

function to create window:

```
           function test(){
            var editWindow = new Ext.Window({
            id: 'editWSWin', 
            layout: 'fit',
            title:this.editPanelTitle,
            autoScroll:false,
            width:300,
            html:'hi'
        });
               return editWindow
             }
```

and call it:

```
, editFormCreate : function (){
    test.show();
}
```

But its undifined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you close the window, it gets destroyed, so you can't show it again. You need to either:

- Set the `closeAction` property on the window
- Create the window inside editFormCreate each time

Comment: I was tried to create function which create window each time i click `Edit` button like in question update. But i get error that function undifined.

Comment: I don't see any update to your question. You only ever create the window when you create the form.

Comment: Im create window in initComponent section becouse i use grid which created in initComponent too in window listeners.

Answer (score 1):

When you close a `Ext.Window`, you dispose of the DOM elements it creates so there is nothing to show anymore. You need to instantiate a new one before showing it in this case.